# Help installing Eclipse svn connector on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, osx-snow-leopard

Installed SVN on Mac OS 10.6.4. Also installed Eclipse and want to use SVN from Eclipse. Found several sites for update/downloading/installing SVN Connector and/or SVN Team Connector and added them to update locations.  Installed SVN Connector, plug-in, etc.

Next tried to Import the SVN structure using SVN connector, but this failed.  Got message: "SVN : Validate Repository location finished error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.... If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: ... Preferences>Team->SVN->SVN Connector...

Went to the Preferences place and found that there were no choices of installed SVN connectors.
Since there appear to be multiple sites for Eclipse SVN integration, which site(s) should I be using?
What do I need to do Import my SVN structure to Eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

I recall just downloading the connectors manually. I had no luck with that automatic thing. I'm using the SVNKit 1.3.3 r6649 (for SVN 1.6.11, all platforms) and it works fine.

You can find the following information at http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

> Subversive distribution consists of two parts - Subversive plug-in and Subversive SVN Connectors. Both parts are required in order to work with Subversive. Subversive plug-in is provided under the terms and conditions of the Eclipse Public License Version 1.0 ("EPL"). A copy of the EPL is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html. Subversive SVN Connectors are external libraries with their own licenses, which are distributed from an external location at www.polarion.com.

Next, go to the polarion site. It says you can use the discovery to find connections, but:

> you can optionally use the update sites below to get them.

The connectors should be located at http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/helios-site/. Use that URL as the repository location.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, if the connectors were installed before or with the base package. I suggest removing all SVN related plug-ins, and starting again:

First by installing the Subversive package, and then after a restart using the Connector Discovery tool to install the connectors. This way I always ended with a working solution.

If this solution does not work for you, then you might also want to try the [Subclipse plug-in](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), that installs both the plug-in and the connectors automatically.

Comment: Subversive is a lot better than subclipse IMO though

Comment: I used Subversive more than Subclipse, so I cannot tell the difference between them. On the other hand, for basic needs both are sufficient, so if one does not work, maybe its worth trying them both.

Comment: If you use subversive, you are able to utilize a lot more of the built-in features for team support that Eclipse normally supplies for repositories live CVS.

Comment: subversive is so, SO much better than subclipse